# Python - when i attempt to loop through an update(), my dict only res

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm currently working on the coding practice project.  I have defined a function, which takes a number of perimeters, all of which are lists.  My goal is to make a single dictionary, which combines an item from each of the list, each at a particular index, together into a single dictionary, where each entry is the element of the list at the corresponding index.  What i have provided below produces no errors, but it seems to be erasing each entry as it adds another, so that all i am left with is a single dictionary entry with all the information at the end of my range, in this case, 34.  How do i make my output, new_dict, is a dictionary of 34 dictionaries?  Why is my `.update` erasing the previous entry each time a new entry is added?

thanks in advance

```
def hurricane_zip(names, months, years, max_sustained_winds, areas_affected, new_damages, deaths):
  new_dict = {}
  new_zip = {}
  for index in range(0,34):
    new_zip.update({"Name": names[index], "Month": months[index], "Year": years[index], "Max Sustained Wind": max_sustained_winds[index], "Areas Affected": areas_affected[index], "Damage": new_damages[index], "Deaths": deaths[index]})
    new_dict.update(new_zip)
  return new_dict
test = hurricane_zip(names, months, years, max_sustained_winds, areas_affected, new_damages, deaths)
print(test)
```

my output is:

```
{'Name': 'Michael', 'Month': 'October', 'Year': 2018, 'Max Sustained Wind': 160, 'Areas Affected': ['Central America', 'United States Gulf Coast (especially Florida Panhandle)'], 'Damage': 25100000000.0, 'Deaths': 74}
```

which is the correct format, but only one of the 34 entries i hoped to create; the last element of each list combined together as a dictionary.

Comment: What are key names you are expecting for new_dict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a dictionary of dictionaries, You could create list of dictionaries, also in case of dictionary of dictionaries you have to define the key names of all dictionaries in new_dict and i think that's not a good idea, find code below:

```
def hurricane_zip(names, months, years, max_sustained_winds, areas_affected, new_damages, deaths):
  data = []  # create list instead of new_dict
  new_zip = {}
  for index in range(0,34):
    new_zip.update({"Name": names[index], "Month": months[index], "Year": years[index], 
        "Max Sustained Wind": max_sustained_winds[index], "Areas Affected": 
        areas_affected[index], "Damage": new_damages[index], "Deaths": deaths[index]})
    data.append(new_zip)
  return data

test = hurricane_zip(names, months, years, max_sustained_winds, areas_affected, 
new_damages, deaths)
print(test)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you!  this makes sense and solves my problem!  out of curiosity, why is it that the .update(), when it was looped, replaced each previous iteration?  My understanding, reading online, was the .update acts similar to .append, essentially "adding" dictionaries together.  Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what my function is doing.

Comment: .update would behave like append in case if you are appending a new key-value in dictionary but in case if dictionary of same keys are appending in dict using update then it would replace the already existing keys value.This is what happening in your case.

Comment: this makes sense!  i tested to make sure i understand, thank you.  I didn't realize you could not have a dictionary with two identical keys

Answer (score 0):

You probably require to declare your collection (new_dict) a list not a dict.

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def hurricane_zip(names, months, years, max_sustained_winds, areas_affected, new_damages, deaths):
  new_dict = []
  new_zip = {}
  for index in range(0,34):
    new_zip.update({"Name": names[index], "Month": months[index], "Year": years[index], "Max Sustained Wind": max_sustained_winds[index], "Areas Affected": areas_affected[index], "Damage": new_damages[index], "Deaths": deaths[index]})
    new_dict.append(new_zip)
  return new_dict
test = hurricane_zip(names, months, years, max_sustained_winds, areas_affected, new_damages, deaths)
print(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> if you store using a key that is already in use, the old value associated with that key is forgotten.

Since I can't quite understand what you want, I will provide two possible solutions:

1. You want to create a list which has 34 dictionaries:

Change *new_dict* to a list, and use *append* instead of *update*.

2. Values of the keys should be lists with 34 entries each:

You need to make sure there is a list associate with your keys in your dictionary before calling append for the keys.
To initialize, you can use something like this: `my_dict={'key1':[], 'key2':[]...}`
You can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from collections to simplify initialization.

Answer (score 0):

1. The dictionaries accept key value pairs, you are trying to update values without key.
2. Dictionary accept one value for one key that the value is either list or tuple or dictionary or string etc. you are trying to add many values(dictionaries), which is not possible

```
    def hurricane_zip(names, months, years, max_sustained_winds, areas_affected, 
    
    new_damages, deaths):
      new_dict = {'hurricaneList': []}
      new_zip = {}
      for index in range(0,34):
        new_zip.update({"Name": names[index], "Month": months[index], "Year": years[index], "Max Sustained Wind": max_sustained_winds[index], "Areas Affected": areas_affected[index], "Damage": new_damages[index], "Deaths": deaths[index]})
        new_dict['hurricaneList'].append(new_zip)
      return new_dict
    test = hurricane_zip(names, months, years, max_sustained_winds, areas_affected, new_damages, deaths)
    print(test)
```

I hope this helps you for your requirement